# Deploying Multiple Features from a single WSP

Tags: 2010, features

I am working with SharePoint 2010. In my solution I have multiple features and event receivers for each feature, and no web part in the solution. I am not sure how to deal with multiple features in a solution. All was working fine with one feature, but as I add another feature, wsp gets deployed but the new feature does not.

Is there anything specific I need to do with regards to multiple features?

Please help me.

Thanks
VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with Visual Studio 2010 make sure that new/old Feature is added in Package.

> You can use the Package Designer to create and customize a package
>   (.wsp). For example, you can add SharePoint project items and
>   Features, specify if the Web server is reset when the solution is
>   deployed, and set the deployment server type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231605.aspx

Comment: Ahh the feature was excluded from package. But I got an error after adding the feature to package.

Comment: Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Failed to create receiver object from assembly "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.Feature, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=54d2cbe44edf3125", class "$SharePoint.Type.423fd1f3-f277-469b-87d6-c7e57f85a754.FullName$" for feature "xxxxxxxxxx.Feature" (ID: 3b5d12ff-d061-425f-8139-7d96404c1b88).: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()

Comment: It seems that SharePoint timer service which handles solution installation caches DLL is still holding the old one. The cached old  DLL has no feature receiver. As a result, the error is Failed to create receiver object from assembly for event receiver. Reset IIS and SharePoint timer job and perform deployment again: http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.se/2011/12/failed-to-create-receiver-object-from.html

Comment: The error message suggest that you have changed/the guid Attribute for the FeatureReceiver class. If you do that you also have to change the xml file for the feature.

Comment: I tried to reset IIS and restart the timer service but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily have multiple features in a single solution, and each of those features can have different scopes (ie: web application and site collection features in the same solution). You do need to ensure that if they have dependencies on one another, those dependencies are setup.

Are you "upgrading" the solution, or retracting and redeploying now that you have your new feature structure. In a lot of cases, unless your code has been setup to compare version numbers, an event receiver that wasn't previously activated will not automatically activate as part of an upgrade. You either need to handle the version difference in code, or do a full retract/deploy.

Comment: I am retracting and redeploying the solution but only the first feature comes up in the features list not the other. Scope of both the features is same "web".

Comment: Double check that they're not set to be hidden, and that they all have unique GUIDs (if you copied the existing solution to create the separate ones, you may have copied the GUID also, but I'd expect it to not build if they were the same). If you do `Get-SPFeature | Where {$_.Scope -eq "Web"}` in PowerShell, do you see all of them, or just the one?